# how to create function for web service in java to get my sql value

Tags: java, mysql, web-services

```
public ArrayList<FeedObjects> GetFeeds(Connection connection) throws Exception
    {
        ArrayList<FeedObjects> feedData = new ArrayList<FeedObjects>();
        try
        {
            //String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT id,title,description,url FROM website ORDER BY id DESC");
            //ps.setString(1,uname);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                FeedObjects feedObject = new FeedObjects();
                feedObject.SetId(rs.getInt("id"));
                feedObject.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
                feedObject.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
                feedObject.setUrl(rs.getString("url"));
                feedData.add(feedObject);
            }
            return feedData;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

and this class to for web service get all database value :

```
@Path("/WebService")
public class FeedService {

    @GET
    @Path("/GetFeeds")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String feed()
    {
        String feeds  = null;
        try 
        {
            ArrayList<FeedObjects> feedData = null;
            ProjectManager projectManager= new ProjectManager();
            feedData = projectManager.GetFeeds();
            //StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            Gson gson = new Gson();


        //  System.out.println(gson.toJson(feedData));
            feeds = gson.toJson(feedData);

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        return feeds;
    }
```

This is mY code from which i am able to display all data from employee table i want write function so that if i pass id then i will get corresponding column values.

```
http://localhost:8080/RESTfulProject/REST/WebService/GetFeeds
```

Using this am Getting all values of Database.

Eg if we input id =1 then it should display only id one emp_name .

please help me and modified me the given function so that i can implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what REST library you are using, but you should search for @PathParam annotation. That allows you to inject the id directly in your code:

```
@GET
@Path("/GetFeeds/{id}")
@Produces("application/json")
public String feedOne(@PathParam int id) {
...
```

And the method get invoked on request

```
http://localhost:8080/RESTfulProject/REST/WebService/GetFeeds/102
```

Comment: can i have email id plz i wills end one small code u can understand plz

Comment: Its  small But 4 classes are there in different package

Comment: Try to send to z8989@mailinator.com . Put your code into the message body do not attach.